# Why we use exports in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am newbie of Nodejs. As per me `module.exports` and `exports` both are empty object. `module.exports` can expose function while `exports` can not to this. Everything can achieve from module.exports.

So, why we use `exports` even we have `module.exports`? what are the advantages of `exports` over `module.exports`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can use:

```
exports.x = 1;
exports.y = 2;
exports.z = 3;
```

as a shorter way of writing:

```
module.exports.x = 1;
module.exports.y = 2;
module.exports.z = 3;
```

The only advantage is less typing.

But you have to write:

```
module.exports = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
};
```

as this will not work:

```
exports = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
};
```

because it wouldn't change the `module.exports` and **it's `module.exports` that actually gets exported**.

### Explanation

Your module gets wrapped in an implicit closure that gets some variables passed as parameters. One of those variables is called `exports` that is an empty object and another one is called `module` and it **includes** `exports` as one of its properties:

```
module.exports === exports
```

When you write:

```
exports.x = 10;
```

then you change the **property** of the provided object (the object is still the same object, but it is mutated) and everything is fine. The value `x` is available as **both** `exports.x` and `module.exports.x`.

But if you write:

```
exports = {x: 10};
```

then you assign a **new object** to `exports` while the `module.exports` is still pointing to the **original** (empty) object. That way you have `exports.x` set correctly but you **don't have** `module.exports.x` set as well, because now:

```
module.exports !== exports
```

If you want to make a **new object** instead of using the empty one that you got in `exports` then you have to assign it to `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = {x: 10};
```

Now `module.exports` and `exports` are different as well:

```
module.exports !== exports
```

But it's `module.exports` that's actually exported so everything is fine.

After assigning a new object to `module.exports` you could assign it to `exports` as well:

```
module.exports = {x: 10};
exports = module.exports;
```

or do it the other way around:

```
exports = {x: 10};
module.exports = exports;
```

so you could still use the shortcut of assigning new properties with:

```
exports.y = 20;
```

but I haven't seen that in practice.

### Real examples

Exporting some functions (public) but not others (private).
Let's say you have those functions:

```
function private1() {
    // ...
}
function private2() {
    // ...
}
function public1() {
    // ...
}
function public2() {
    // ...
}
```

You have few options to export two public functions:

#### This works

```
module.exports.public1 = public1;
module.exports.public2 = public2;
```

or:

```
exports.public1 = public1;
exports.public2 = public2;
```

or:

```
module.exports = {
    public1: public1,
    public2: public2
};
```

or:

```
module.exports = {
    public1,
    public2
};
```

#### This doesn't work

```
exports = {
    public1: public1,
    public2: public2
};
```

or:

```
exports = {
    public1,
    public2
};
```

### Summary

In other words, `exports` is just for **convenience** so that you don't have to write `module.exports` every time, but it **doesn't work** for cases when you want to export a different object than the one provided to you originally. In that case you need to set the `module.exports` to that new object.

### See also

See also this answer:

- **[What is the difference between module.export and export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397761/what-is-the-difference-between-module-export-and-export/43398667#43398667)**

Comment: Wowww..awesome explaination

Answer (score 2):

module is a plain JavaScript object with an exports property. exports is a plain JavaScript variable that happens to be set to module.exports. At the end of your file, node.js will basically 'return' module.exports to the require function. A simplified way to view a JS file in Node could be this:

```
// your code
var module = { exports: {} };
var exports = module.exports;

return module.exports;
```

If you set a property on exports, like exports.a = 9;, that will set module.exports.a as well because objects are passed around as references in JavaScript, which means that if you set multiple variables to the same object, they are all the same object; so then exports and module.exports are the same object.
But if you set exports to something new, it will no longer be set to module.exports, so exports and  module.exports are no longer the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Convenience. Typing `exports.myFunc = function(){};` is shorter than `module.exports.myFunc = function(){};`

Answer (score 0):

with `module.exports` you can export the entire module to be imported in other node modules where all the functions are made accessible from the exported module.

with indepdendent `exports` you can export only the methods which you wish to be made accessible to other modules. It's like making certain functions as `public` & `private`.

Comment: That's not what the question is asking.

Comment: Question is asked about advantages of using `module.exports` vs. `exports`. What do you think the question is about?

Comment: The question is asking why we would ever use the plain `exports` object when we have `module.exports`. You have it backwards.

Comment: Yes, and that's what i have responded with. Check my response again.

Comment: You can do the exact same thing with `module.exports` by doing `module.exports.myMethod = something`. The only reason we don't do that is convenience, as i say in my answer.