# How to access Object value from external js

Tags: node.js

When I try to access object value from external js file I'm getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewport' of undefined

**test-diff.js**

```
var GlobalConfigs = require('./global-config.js');
console.log(GlobalConfigs.GlobalConfig.viewport.desktop);
```

**global-config.js**

```
GlobalConfig = {
   viewport: {
        desktop: "960",
        laptop: "320"
    },
    startPage: "10",
    totalPages: "7",
    threshold: "5"
 }
```

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342935/how-to-access-object-value-from-external-js/41342973#41342973) below help you? Any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with other answer listed, however, I think having additional variable might be unnecessary.

```
module.exports = {
    viewport: {
        desktop: 960,
        laptop: 320
    },
    startPage: 10,
    totalPages: 7,
    threshold: 5
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to export the object that you want to access with `require`.

Change:

```
GlobalConfig = {
   viewport: {
        desktop: "960",
        laptop: "320"
    },
    startPage: "10",
    totalPages: "7",
    threshold: "5"
 }
```

to:

```
exports.GlobalConfig = {
   viewport: {
        desktop: "960",
        laptop: "320"
    },
    startPage: "10",
    totalPages: "7",
    threshold: "5"
};
```

I would also use numbers instead of strings:

```
exports.GlobalConfig = {
   viewport: {
        desktop: 960,
        laptop: 320
    },
    startPage: 10,
    totalPages: 7,
    threshold: 5
};
```

For more details on how modules requiring and exporting works and what's the difference between `exports` and `module.exports` see this answer:

- [Why we use exports in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280537/why-we-use-exports-in-nodejs/41281525#41281525)

For general documentation on modules in Node, see:

- https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use module.exports. Use this code
`GlobalConfig = {
   viewport: {
        desktop: "960",
        laptop: "320"
    },
    startPage: "10",
    totalPages: "7",
    threshold: "5"
 }
module.exports.GlobalConfig = GlobalConfig;`