# What is the difference between module.export and export

Tags: node.js

What is the difference between `module.export` and `export`？

What if there are some attributes in module.export object？ 
Will `export.xx` be invalid then ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all it's `exports` and `module.exports` and not `export` and `module.export` (there is also an `export` keyword in JavaScript but it is not supported in Node yet).

Every Node module is wrapped with this function:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  // Your module code actually lives in here
});
```

See: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper

Your module doesn't return the exported object from that functions as some people think. It can only pass data to the caller by **adding properties to the arguments provided**.

`module.exports` and `exports` are **initially the same object** - but it is `module.exports` that is **actually exported** if they end up to be not the same object.

It means that this will work the same:

```
module.exports.x = 1;
# or:
exports.x = 1;
```

because it changes the property of **the same object**.

But this **will not** be the same:

```
module.exports = {x: 1};
```

as this:

```
exports = {x: 1};
```

The last one will **not export** the `x` because it will **substitute** the object in `exports` (that was originally **the same** object as `module.exports`) while leaving the default empty object in `module.exports` to be actually exported.

The `module.exports = {x: 1};` **also substitutes** a new object but it puts it where it needs to be to actually get exported. Note that this instruction `changes the property` of the `module` object, which can be seen by the caller after the implicit function that your module is wrapped in returns.

Now this would work:

```
exports = {x: 1};
module.exports = exports;
```

because it substitutes the object in `exports` with a new one but it also puts it into `module.exports`.

Remember that it is always `module.exports` that matters at the end if you didn't substitute one of them with a new object then you can use them interchangeably when setting their attributes:

```
exports.x = 1;
module.exports.y = 2;
```

For more info see this answer:

- **[Why we use exports in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280537/why-we-use-exports-in-nodejs/41281525#41281525)**

Answer (score 3):

**Module** is object and **exports** is a property(variable) of module object.

```
const module = { 
   //property
   exports: {} 
};
```

**exports** is shortcut for **module.exports** until it is assigned with new object

1. #### exports === module.exports

   ```
   module.exports.hello = true;
   exports.hello = true;
   ```
2. #### exports !== module.exports

   ```
   module.exports.hello = true;
   exports = { hello: true };
   ```

   *exports* property is completely replaced by new object.

[Reference](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

```
function require(/* ... */) {
   const module = { exports: {} };
   ((module, exports) => {
      // Your module code here. In this example, define a function.
      function someFunc() {}
      exports = someFunc;
      // At this point, exports is no longer a shortcut to 
      // module.exports, and
      // this module will still export an empty default object.
      module.exports = someFunc;
      // At this point, the module will now export someFunc, instead of 
      //the default object.
    })(module, module.exports);
   return module.exports;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the `module.exports` is actually what the `require` function return, when you pass the path of your script to require function , your codes will wrap and run in a function expression which have a parameter named `exports` which is an empty object and then `module.exports` will pass to it. generally it's a shorthand to `module.exports` and in other words, it's two variables pointing at same object in memory, so it seems similar, right?

but actually there is a difference, `exports` act different in some patterns, lets give u an example about these kind of patterns, lets say we have a script named tada.js :

```
exports = function(){
    console.log('Tada');
}

console.log(exports);
console.log(module.exports);
```

if I require this script in my app.js :

```
var tada = require('./tada');
```

then what do you expect to see?

well, this is going to be the output:

```
console.log(exports); // [Function]
console.log(module.exports); // {}
```

it show `exports` as a function and `module.exports` as an empty object. but, as I told you, these two are just two variables pointing at same object in memory, passed by reference, so are they not suppose to have same value? well, maybe in any other language, it will act like that, but in JavaScript things are a little different.

In JavaScript if we use `=` to assign a value, it actually make a new object in memory, so in other words, in our example, that `reference` between `exports` and `module.exports` will broken, that mean `exports` and `module.exports` originally point to same object in memory, but when we did this :

```
exports = function(){
    console.log('Tada');
}
```

that reference broken and now `exports` is point to a new object in memory.

also remember that require function only return `module.exports`, not `exports` so that's why we got empty object for `module.exports` in our example and since reference broken, `module.exports` , `exports` are no longer pointing to same object.

To fix this, u need to `mutate` instead of overwrite. so if we change our example to this, then both `exports` and `module.exports` will have same value :

```
exports.tada = function(){
    console.log('Tada');
}

console.log(exports);
console.log(module.exports);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will explain all:

//page2.js

```
 exports = () => { console.log("Foo") };
 module.exports = () => { console.log("Bar") };
```

//app.js

```
  const myFunc = require("./page2");
  myFunc();    //output : Bar
```